# Gradle -- execute multiple commands from task

Tags: extjs, gradle

I have 2 separate apps (in one project) that require 2 separate builds (sencha cmd). I have been asked to create a gradle script that will do the builds for both apps.

I created a task that builds one app, but am having troubles using the same task to build the 2nd app.

This is what I have so far:

```
task senchaCmdBuild (type: Exec) {
  workingDir 'src/main/app/MYAPP'
  commandLine 'cmd', 'c', 'sencha app build'
}
```

and this works fine.

When I add the following 2 lines to above task:

```
 workingDir 'src/main/app/MYOTHERAPP'
 commandLine 'cmd', 'c', 'sencha app build'
```

the first command is ignored and only the second command executes.

So is there anyway I can execute both commands with one task?

Comment: create two `Exec` tasks and run them both from a master task.

Comment: I feel like there must be a solution where you could leverage `&&` on the commandLine to execute multiple things. Alternatively, you could just invoke a shell script that did both.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use the second way to declare task types on gradle.

```
task senchaCmdBuild {
  doLast {
    exec {
      workingDir 'src/main/app/MYAPP'
      commandLine 'cmd', 'c', 'sencha app build'
    }
    exec {
      workingDir 'src/main/app/MYOTHERAPP'
      commandLine 'cmd', 'c', 'sencha app build'
    }
  }
}
```

You need put the exec method in doLast in order to be executed only on execution flow

Comment: If you're doing this inside a plugin, you need to use `project.exec` (as well as `project.task`) to call the proper DSL methods.

Comment: Is there a way to only run the second command if the first one fails?

Comment: @NoahAndrews I currently writting different syntax for that, it taken from groovy.

With this you can execute something:
def result = "echo 1".execute()


With this you wait until finish:
result.waitFor()

and with this you get result value:
result.exitValue()

Answer (score 9):

It's impossible to configure (run) multiple commands for the task of type `Exec`. `commandLine` it's just a setter - the last one wins. If you need to run multiple commands the best idea is to implement multiple tasks as @RaGe suggested in the comment or to write a custom task and use groovy's native mechanisms - `execute` method.

Answer (score 8):

You also can use **gradle methods** instead create fictive tasks

```
task senchaBuild() {
 doLast {
    senchaBuild_steps()
 }
}

void senchaBuild_steps() {
 exec {
    workingDir 'src/main/app/MYAPP'
    commandLine 'cmd', 'c', 'sencha app build'
 }
 exec {
    workingDir 'src/main/app/MYOTHERAPP'
    commandLine 'cmd', 'c', 'sencha app build'
 }
}
```

Comment: great, that makes me life (build :)) easier !

Answer (score 1):

Use .execute() at doLast block

```
task myTask(group: "my-group") {
       doLast {
             println "Starting..."
             println "echo \"MyEcho1\"".execute().text.trim()
             println "echo \"MyEcho2\"".execute().text.trim()
       }
    }
```