# Execute more than one command in a task without breaking incremental build

Tags: gradle, incremental-build

We use gradle incremental builds and want to run two commands (ideally from one task). One of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561014/gradle-execute-multiple-commands-from-task) worked getting the two commands running... however it breaks incremental builds.. It looks something like:

```
task myTask() {
inputs.files(inputFiles)

  project.exec {
     workingDir web
     commandLine('mycmd')
  }
  project.exec {
    workingDir web
    commandLine('mysecond-cmd')
  }
}
```

if running a single command and incremental builds is working, the task looked similar to this, the thing that seems to make the difference is the `workingDir`:

```
task myTask(type: Exec)  {
     workingDir  myDir // this seems to trigger/enable continuos compilation
    commandLine ('myCmd')
 }
```

the best alternative so far is create 3 tasks, one for each of the cmdline tasks I want to run and a third one to group them, which seems dirty.

The question is: Is there a way to run two or more commands in one task with incremental builds still working?

Comment: I had a look at the code for `Exec` and `workingDir` is not considered for up-to-date checks. Do these commands generate files? Incremental build generally only works if you have both declared inputs _and_ outputs. `myTask` only declares inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the commands only run a build step with no intersting output files.

Comment: How is Gradle supposed to know whether it needs to run the command again? I can't see anything that automatically creates and registers a file to prove that the command has run. BTW, you've used "incremental build", "incremental compilation" and "continuous compilation", which are all different things. Perhaps it would help if you could clarify exactly what you want to happen. In what way was "incremental compilation working" with the single command?

Comment: I consolidated to incremental build, I am looking for the feature that will trigger a build when files have changed ... as to how it's gradle supposed to know, well that is part of the question, it would be great to know how incremental builds work (as in, how can I signal from a task that has no output files that those the build should watch certain files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer the question from the comments: how can I signal from a task that has no output files that the build should watch certain files. Unfortunately, this is hard to answer without knowing the exact use case.

To start with, Gradle requires some form of declared output that it can check to see whether a task has run or whether it needs to run. Consider that the task may have failed during the previous run, but the input files haven't changed since then. Should Gradle run the task?

If you have a task that doesn't have any outputs, that means you need to think about why that task should run or not in any given build execution. What's it doing if it's not creating or modifying files or interacting with another part of the system?

Assuming that incremental build is the right solution — it may not be — Gradle does allow you to handle unusual scenarios via [`TaskOutputs.upToDateWhen(Action)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks). Here's an example that has a straightforward task (`gen`) that generates a file that acts as an input for a task (`runIt`) with no outputs:

```
task gen {
    ext.outputDir = "$buildDir/stuff"
    outputs.dir outputDir

    doLast {
        new File(outputDir, "test.txt").text = "Hurray!\n"
    }
}

task runIt {
    inputs.dir gen
    outputs.upToDateWhen { !gen.didWork }
    doLast {
        println "Running it"
    }
}
```

This specifies that `runIt` will only run if the input files have changed or the task `gen` actually did something. In this example, those two scenarios equate to the same thing. If `gen` runs, then the input files for `runIt` have changed.

The key thing to understand is that the condition you provide to `upToDateWhen()` is evaluated during the *execution* phase of the build, not the configuration phase.

Hope that helps, and if you need any clarification, let me know.